# Why can my `no_std` program compile even if it depends on `std` somehow

Tags: rust

I have a `src/lib.rs`:

```rust
#![no_std]

#[macro_use]
extern crate derive_builder;

extern crate alloc;

#[derive(Builder)]
#[builder(no_std)]
struct Foo {
    bar: i32,
}
```

And `Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "foo"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Foo Bar <foobar@example.com>"]
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
derive_builder = { version = "0.10.1", default-features = false }
```

This program compiles with the following command:

```
cargo build
```

However, when I specify a target that doesn't have the `std` crate, it will not compile.

```
> cargo build --target=x86_64-unknown-uefi -Z build-std=core,alloc,compiler_builtins
    Updating crates.io index
   Compiling strsim v0.10.0
   Compiling fnv v1.0.7
   Compiling ident_case v1.0.1
   Compiling proc-macro2 v1.0.26
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `std`
  |
  = note: the `x86_64-unknown-uefi` target may not be installed

error[E0463]: can't find crate for `std`
  |
  = note: the `x86_64-unknown-uefi` target may not be installed

error: aborting due to previous error

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0463`.
For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0463`.
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `std`
  |
  = note: the `x86_64-unknown-uefi` target may not be installed

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0463`.
error: could not compile `ident_case`

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `std`
  |
  = note: the `x86_64-unknown-uefi` target may not be installed

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0463`.
error: build failed
```

My question is: why the program compiles if I don't specify a target for it? Since it is the `no_std` one, if it depends on `std` either directly or indirectly (except the proc macros), the program shouldn't compile.

#### Environment

```
cargo 1.53.0-nightly (65d57e6f3 2021-04-04)
```

```
> rustc --print cfg
debug_assertions
panic="unwind"
target_arch="x86_64"
target_endian="little"
target_env="gnu"
target_family="unix"
target_feature="fxsr"
target_feature="sse"
target_feature="sse2"
target_has_atomic="16"
target_has_atomic="32"
target_has_atomic="64"
target_has_atomic="8"
target_has_atomic="ptr"
target_has_atomic_equal_alignment="16"
target_has_atomic_equal_alignment="32"
target_has_atomic_equal_alignment="64"
target_has_atomic_equal_alignment="8"
target_has_atomic_equal_alignment="ptr"
target_has_atomic_load_store="16"
target_has_atomic_load_store="32"
target_has_atomic_load_store="64"
target_has_atomic_load_store="8"
target_has_atomic_load_store="ptr"
target_os="linux"
target_pointer_width="64"
target_thread_local
target_vendor="unknown"
unix
```

Comment: Is this a *library* or a *program*? Because you show the contents of `lib.rs`, but your cargo toml doesn't explicitely specify whether it's a lib or bin (or both). If you have executable entry points, these also need to be `#![no_std]`.

Comment: @Masklinn It's a library. The only Rust file of this crate is `lib.rs`.

Comment: It looks like this is an issue with proc macro libs having dependencies on std features for compile-time shenanigans, similar to https://github.com/illicitonion/num_enum/issues/18 here derive-builder (core) depends on `darling` which depends on `darling_core` which depends on `ident_case`.. which depends on std. Therefore cargo tries to pull in std. If you were building `no_std` with a toolchain having std it'd probavbly fail at runtime (as with the num_enum issue), here the toolchain doesn't even have `std` so it fails at compile-time.

Comment: @Masklinn Thank you for your comment. I sent [a comment](https://github.com/colin-kiegel/rust-derive-builder/issues/201#issuecomment-823838755) to an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [the comment from Masklinn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67189725/why-can-my-no-std-program-compile-even-if-it-depends-on-std-somehow#comment118765287_67189725) says, the `derive-builder` crate indirectly depended on the `ident_case`, which depended on `std`.

This problem is fixed by [this patch](https://github.com/colin-kiegel/rust-derive-builder/pull/206).